# Tile a spline with bricks

Tags: interpolation, tiling, spline

I have a series of identically sized virtual Lego bricks. I need to "tile" these bricks along the length of a Hermite spline to create a curved road. The spline is two-dimensional. E.g. the curve only rises or falls. It does not turn left or right.

How do I go about doing this? The bricks all need to remain connected to each other.

Here are two examples of real and virtual curved Lego roads.

http://gallaghersart.com/images/made/item/1000/700_560_78/GallaghersArt_ramp_04_a_sm.jpg

http://www.flickr.com/photos/12333864@N05/3646860002

Thanks!

Comment: What is the question here? You are measuring out equal distances on a curve; what's the problem? $t_{i+1}=\inf\{t>t_i:|f(t)-f(t_i)|\ge1\}$ will give you points $f(t_1),f(t_2),\dots$ along your curve that all have unit distances between them.

Comment: I don't understand your syntax. Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: Given $t_i$, let $t_{i+1}$ be the smallest number bigger than $t_i$ such that the distance from $f(t_{i+1})$ to $f(t_i)$ is at least $1$. Then if $f$ is any continuous function, $f(t_{i+1})$ will be exactly $1$ unit away from $f(t_i)$ (assuming that $f$ eventually gets far enough away). Keep doing this, and you get a nice sequence of points that are equally spaced along the curve. (I am assuming the curve is given as a continuous function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^k$.)

Comment: Crap, I don't understand any of this. I'm going to the programming section where reviewers can provide pseudo code.

Comment: If you want a programmer's answer, you should have said so. A hermite spline is a polynomial thing, and so finding distances on it is a bit of a mess; you'll have to do root finding. For example: you have some number `t1` and `f(t1)` gives some point. Calculate `f(t1+1)` and measure the distance to `f(t1)`. If it is too far, try `f(t1+1/2)`; otherwise try `f(t1+2)`. Keep upper and lower bounds on guesses and bound them closer together. Eventually you'll get a number for which `f(t1+u)` is almost exactly one unit away from `f(t1)`; then let `t2=t1+u` and start over.

Comment: OK, I went ahead with your approach with some success. I was able to calculate the center points of the bricks. However, the bricks are supposed to be angled to form the smooth curve. I have the derivative at each point. What do I do now with it? The software I'm using accepts a "rotation matrix" ([here](http://www.mr-bucket.co.uk/Business/Project/ExtractAngles.html)) if that helps, but I can work with angles in degrees or radians as well.

Comment: I don't think the suggested approach is quite correct, anyway. It assumes that Lego bricks have zero thickness, which is not true, of course. If the curve of the road is fairly gentle, it might be OK, I guess.

Comment: Mario if you want to make an official answer I will mark it as the solution. Everything is working peachy right now.